# concatenate leading spaces in SAS

Tags: sas, concatenation

I want to indent Male and Female.
[image: current F_SEX]
this is my data:

```
data T_SEX
retain SEX _7_ug_kg_day _9_ug_kg_day _12_ug_kg_day Total;
set T_SEX;
keep SEX _7_ug_kg_day _9_ug_kg_day _12_ug_kg_day Total;
by descending SEX;
if _9_ug_kg_day=" " then _9_ug_kg_day="0";
rename SEX=CHARA;
run;

data labelSEX;
length CHARA $50;
CHARA="Sex n(%)";
run;
data F_SEX;
set labelSEX T_SEX; run;
```

I tried to put an if statement followed by `||""variable`, but I couldn't figure it out.
Expected output:

```
Characteristics   7ugkgday 9ugkgday 12ugkgday total
Sex
  male            xxx(xxx) xxx(xxx) xxx(xxx)  xxx(xxx)
  female          xxx(xxx) xxx(xxx) xxx(xxx)  xxx(xxx)
```

Comment: Do you want to produce a report? or do you want it to be indented inside the table?

Comment: I would want it indented inside the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the below what you are looking for?

1. Create sample data sets

```
data labelsex;
    infile datalines delimiter='|' dsd;
    input chara :$10.;
    datalines;
Sex n(%)||||
;

data have;
    infile datalines delimiter='|' dsd;
    input chara :$10. _7ug_kg_day :$10. _9_ug_kg_day :$10. _12_ug_kg_day :$10. 
        Total :$10.;
    datalines;
Male|2 (66.7%)|3 ( 100%)|7 (70.0%)|12 (75.0%)
Female|1 (33.3%)||3 (30.0%)|4 (25.0%)
;
```

2. Compress to remove unexpected blanks
3. Replace missing character value by `0(0%)`
4. Indent using the [`repeat()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p0p9jw1m2698fvn1ljrnc8b6gij6.htm) function. Here it is 3 times a blank space.

```
data t_sex;
    length chara :$20.;
    set have;
    array char $ _character_;

    do over char;
        char = compress(char);
        if missing(char) then
            char='0(0%)';
    end;
    
    chara = cat(repeat(' ', 3), chara);
run;
```

5. Rename the chara column to Characteristics
6. Set the two data sets together

```
data want;
    set labelsex t_sex;
    rename chara=Characteristics;
run;
```

[image]

However I don't see why you would want to indent inside a SAS table. To me it looks like you want to produce some kind of report as an output. If that is the case, I would suggest to use SAS procedures that were design to do so like [PROC REPORT](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n1dz7jdasx5t56n1rmlx346dyk6n.htm) or [PROC TABULATE](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n00yutbvvckjwrn1ldg5xkvjy1pu.htm).

---

An example using PROC REPORT

```
proc report data=t_sex nowd style(report)={rules=none frame=void cellspacing=0};
    title1 'Example using PROC REPORT';
    column chara _7ug_kg_day _9_ug_kg_day _12_ug_kg_day total;
    define chara / group order descending 'Characteristics' style(column)={cellwidth=0.5 indent=10};
    define _7ug_kg_day / center display '7ugkgday';
    define _9_ug_kg_day / center display '9ugkgday ';
    define _12_ug_kg_day / center display '12ugkgday ';
    define total / center display 'Total';
    compute before / style={just=l font_weight=bold};
        line 'Sex n(%)';
    endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I mistook what you meant. Yes it is going through proc report. Could you show me how that can be done? Thank you